# When connecting to PC, App Icons are listed

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

My boss has a Samsung Galaxy s4 mini and whenever he connects it to his PC via USB to copy pictures he shot, there are also lots of what looks like App-Icons listed in the windows explorer. They return whenever he restarts the phone. Is there something i can do to help him?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? A screenshot of what you're seeing would help us to see what's going on. Also try to check whether it really is an S4 or something else.

Comment: Is he seeing these icons on the phone's screen, or on the PC's screen?

Answer (score 0):

The App-like icons are most probably Thumbnails saved in system for various images. What you can do, is image copy program to only look for image files in specific folders (e.g. DCIM folder on sdcard), as now it seems image program is scanning android phone for all images to copy them.

Other than that, different applications can be creating those thumbnail files and they are here to speedup browsing of image files on your phone. I do not think there is any uniform way of disabling these across android system and applications, thus you should try setting up software which downloads images.